# How do we bind data to a `footer` in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do we bind data to a `footer` inside `ListView` in Xamarin Forms, here I would need to pass the `count_in` value to footer.

```
<ListView  x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.Footer>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Count}" BackgroundColor="Gray"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ListView.Footer>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding image}" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                            <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" TextColor="#f35e20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="2">
                            <Label Text="{Binding SoccerStatus}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#503026"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="3">
                            <Label Text="{Binding CurrentDate}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#503026"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

Below is the DisplayCount() gets the count from database;

```
 public void DisplayCount()
        {
           var datetoday = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
           var count_in = (from x in conn.Table<SoccerAvailability>().Where(x => string.Equals(x.SoccerStatus, "IN", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && x.CurrentDate == datetoday) select x).Count();

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now getting database exception SQLite exception no such function
>   equals

This is because SQLLite linq doesn't recognize the `string.Equals` method. You could convert it to list using `ToListAsync` for one condition. Then filter the c# list object using equals:

```
var datetoday = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");

var items = await conn.Table<SoccerAvailability>().Where(x => x.CurrentDate == datetoday).ToListAsync();
var finalsItems = items.Where(x => string.Equals(x.SoccerStatus, "IN", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();

Count = finalsItems.Count();
```

At last, binding your Lable's Text to this Count property.

**Edit about binding:**

Have you set your content page to your ViewModel? Moreover, implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your view model:

```
// Set your page's binding context
BindingContext = new PageViewModel();

public class PageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int count;
    public int Count
    {
        set
        {
            if (count != value)
            {
                count = value;
                onPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return count;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void onPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Edit2:**

If you didn't use view model, set a name to your footer label:

```
<ListView.Footer>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="FooterLabel" BackgroundColor="Gray"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ListView.Footer>
```

Then set its value directly:

```
//...
FooterLabel.Text = finalsItems.Count().ToString();
```

Comment: Lu : I have handled the input text converted to upper case before saving to database as someone advised.While setting a break point, I am receiving count_in = 1 , but the count is not displaying in the footer Text="{Binding Count}" it is displaying as 0

Comment: @ what is this `BindingContext = new PageViewModel();`

Comment: @soccerway This is your page's binding context, if you want to use view model to handle your data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics​​​​​​​. If you didn't use binding for your page. Please see my edit.

Comment: Now this got displayed successfully, if we have single item to display in 'view' why we need to have to choose `Binding` property..we could use the same way as you adivised right ?

Comment: @soccerway Before using binding we should set the controls' binding context. It points out what view model they are consuming. I guess you are meaning list view, you set the view cell's binding context using listview's items source. Read the documentation I posted above precisely about binding.

Answer (score 2):

you are binding to Count

```
<Label Text="{Binding Count}" BackgroundColor="Gray"></Label>
```

so Count needs to be a public property on your ViewModel

```
public int Count { get; set; }
```

Comment: But how to pass `count_in` value to `Text="{Binding Count}"` . I have set Count to be public property in ViewModel

Comment: Count = count_in;

Comment: Getting database exception,

Comment: Now getting database exception `SQLite exception no such function equals`

Comment: Where(x => x.SoccerStatus == "IN")

Comment: Ok, but will i get the count of IN regardless of the SoccerStatus been saved in database as like `IN, in, In`,

Comment: You should take steps to prevent bad data from getting into your db.  Use an enum instead of a string.  Or you can modify the setter for the property to always enforce a consistent casing.

Comment: I have handled the input `text` converted to upper case before saving as you said.While setting a break point, I am receiving `count_in = 1` , but the count is not displaying in the footer  `Text="{Binding Count}"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the binding context for the footer.

By default for footers, headers, and templates in a list view, its binding context is going to be the item currently being displayed. So in this case `Count` would need to be a public property on the item from `ItemsSource`. Point the `Count` binding at your view model instead.

```
<Label Text="{Binding BindingContext.Count, Source={x:Reference xNameSetForCurrentPage}" BackgroundColor="Gray"></Label>
```

`xNameSetForCurrentPage` is the `x:Name="name"` set at the top most element(where all the xmlns stuff is) of the page.

Comment: I will give a try with that

Comment: Now getting database exception `SQLite exception no such function equals`